# Copy image out of Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a few embedded images in a Microsoft Word document, is there anyway to copy the images out as jpeg files?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Although [Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V is a good approach](https://superuser.com/a/40898/522), but a better way is to save the MS word file as webpage, and get the jpg file.

The reason I said this is because Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V will generate a resolution loss in the picture. OTOH, if you save the Microsoft Word to HTML, then all the image size, and the original picture resolution will be preserved.

Comment: If the image has been resized when inserted into Word then the JPEG image will be a lower quality resized image. This is particularly noticeable for screen grabs containing text. Word 2007 also produces a full size PNG image with 'Save as Web Page' which will be the original quality.  As T Kaltnekar pointed out, this is also available by opening the .docx file in 7-Zip.

Comment: very nice! +1 ...

Comment: +1 I think this solution is better because you can see the images in the context.

Comment: one other option is right click on the picture. Format Menu -> Adjust Group -> Reset Picture (dropdown) -> Reset Picture and Size. This will bring the original picture back in the file. Now copy it ctrl+c and paste ctrl+v anywhere you like with original full resolution. This also can be done through right click on picture -> size and position context menu -> click reset button. this will bring original size. now ctrl+c and ctrl+v. press ctrl +z (undo) to bring it back to the previous version as it was in the document.

Answer (score 34):

If you are using Word 2007 you can open *.docx in 7-zip, since it is basically just a zip archive. Images are located in folder word\media. A bit more direct approach to saving as html but obviously won't work in older versions of Word.

Comment: I did not know this, nice tip! :)

Comment: You can also rename the .docx file to .zip and open it in the file explorer.

Comment: one other option is right click on the picture. Format Menu -> Adjust Group -> Reset Picture (dropdown) -> Reset Picture and Size. This will bring the original picture back in the file. Now copy it ctrl+c and paste ctrl+v anywhere you like with original full resolution.
This also can be done through right click on picture -> size and position context menu -> click reset button. this will bring original size. now ctrl+c and ctrl+v.
press ctrl +z (undo) to bring it back to the previous version as it was in the document.

Answer (score 5):

Right click -> Save Picture...

Comment: Simple, and keeps the original resolution.

Comment: this is a good solution.. but i wish there is a right click -> save picture to clipboard :-) saving the picture is a pain in the you know what!

Answer (score 3):

Just copy and paste them into an image editing program (even ms paint will do) and then save as a jpeg.

Comment: This way you get a low-resolution image.

Comment: Yup, very old suggestion some of the others are much better. I like the save as web page option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) with the `extract-media` argument to
convert a Microsoft Word document to markdown. Images will be stored in the figures/media directory:

```
pandoc --extract-media figures input.docx -o output.md
```

Answer (score -1):

Select the image and copy it to clipboard in the normal fashion (either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or click "Edit" then "Copy".

Next, go in to Accessories > Microsoft Paint, (<kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> / Start > Run then type "mspaint")

Next hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or "Edit" then "paste"

Save the file and done!

Comment: This way you get a low-resolution image.

Comment: @JoseGómez - unless changed in recent versions, you get the original - so, if pasted in to word, it keeps the size meta data. If pasted in to pain, it has the original image.

Comment: At least with Office 2010, you get a low-resolution image. Not sure if that has been fixed in later versions.

Comment: Copy and Paste gets you a rather useless low-res image. I am currently using Word for Office 365 16.x and don't recall that this ever worked and differently. I have to admit, though, that my memory gets a bit cloudy when we go back to Windows NT and earlier versions ....

Answer (score -1):

Copy-paste from Word to another software (e.g. PowerPoint, Irfanview as suggested above) results in reduced resolution image in most cases (Word adjusts the resolution according to the page layout). Using 7zip as suggested works nicely, but if you don't have it, you can also rename a .docx file to .zip file and then use Windows capability of looking into contents - look for a folder called "media".