# Can I export a PNG image from Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, images, png

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy Image Out Of Microsoft Word](https://superuser.com/questions/40894/copy-image-out-of-microsoft-word)

Someone sent me a doc file with a picture in it. Probably it is a ***.png**.

I want to save the picture in order to paste it to other apps. I need it to act like a ***.png**, meaning that the background is transparent.

Can I export the picture from Word? Can I make an image using print screen and make the white background transparent?

Comment: Is this an old (Office2003) .doc file or an (Office2007+) .docx file?  If it is ther later then there is an even better way to get to the image file...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you own PowerPoint:

- mark the picture in word and hit ctrl-c to copy it into the clipboard
- open powerpoint and insert the picture there with ctrl-v
- right-click the picture and select "save as picture

another solution without powerpoint is to save the word file as web page (*.html), see here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/itdojo/save-images-in-microsoft-word-documents-as-separate-files/135

Answer (score 6):

If it is a Word2007 or 2010 file, you can access the images directly:

1. Using a copy of the document (so you don't accidentally screw up the original), change the **.docx** extension to **.zip**
2. Using Windows Explorer or your favorite compression application, explore the zip file contents
3. The images will be in a subfolder   YourFile.zip/word/media/image1.png, image2.png, etc.
4. Copy-paste that image to wherever you want.

This also works with PowerPoint and Excel.