# How to dismantle word document

Tags: microsoft-word, export

I have been given a set of reports from several experiments. Each experiment contains of several steps and each step has one `docx` report containing images placed "in text".

Is there any way how to extract all images at once? I can export them separately, but it seems to be a waste of time.

Comment: Perhaps also see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/40939/23133) to [Copy Image Out Of Microsoft Word](http://superuser.com/questions/40894/copy-image-out-of-microsoft-word).

Comment: @CharlieRB Ctrl+A, R-click, save as image.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The trick with "rename it as `.zip` file and unpack" is very neat trick!

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/807639/20953